# Is there a way to match specific points for correspondence?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, homography

I am trying to compute the homography matrix between the two images

[points extracted from real-life image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTAAw.png)

these are the points I was able to extract ( with some outliers)

[manually extracted points from 2d model image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxXFK.jpg)

this is the 2d model field and the highlighted points are points I manually extracted

In order to compute the homography matrix, we need 4-point correspondences.
now I have good points in both images, but I can't find a way to automatically match these points.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [findHomography](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780), for example:

```
homog, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_points, dst_points, cv2.RANSAC)
```

Then warp the image with [warpPerspective](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87):

```
im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(src, homog, (dst.shape[1],dst.shape[0]))
```

Comment: I did but the problem is that src_points and dst_points have to be in the order of correspondence.

Comment: Each point in source must match point in destination. I suggest you start with just four points. Help selecting the points in the source by drawing each point (you already did it in green) and its index on the source image. Then pick from destination in the same order.

Comment: first of all thanks for your comment. that is why I asked the question, I can't find a way to know which point corresponds to which as in the real-life image, not all the corners are visible, so src_points and dst_points are not in the same order. I even tried to sort them by their y-axis position, but that didn't work as not all corners are visible